# SQL Triggers: Are they fired after a statement or a transaction?

Tags: sql, transactions, triggers

I'm looking for an answer to whether triggers in SQL are fired immediately following an action caused by a statement, or only after the entire transaction is committed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, `AFTER` triggers are fired immediately following an action caused by a statement. (A transaction can be rolled back by a trigger).

There are also `INSTEAD OF` triggers which fire in place of the triggering action.

[DML Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers)

[CREATE TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

Also of interest: Joe Celko's [Triggers: Threat or Menace?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/triggers-threat-menace/)

Comment: The link just goes to a top level MSDN magazine page, do you know which issue it was in?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Fixed up with new links.